Sample variance of residual series of an AR($p$) model
Ruey Tsay writes on pages 49-50 of his book Analysis of Financial Time Series (Third Edition):

For a specified AR($p$) model in Eq. (2.9), the conditional least-squares method, which starts with the $(p+1)$th observation, is often used to estimate the parameters. Specifically, conditioning on the first $p$ observations, we have
$$r_t = \phi_0 + \phi_1r_{t-1}+\cdots+\phi_pr_{t-p}+a_t,\qquad t=p+1,\dots,T,$$
which is in the form of a multiple linear regression and can be estimated by the least-squares method. Denote the estimate of $\phi_i$ by $\hat\phi_i$. The fitted model is
$$\hat r_t = \hat\phi_0 + \hat\phi_1r_{t-1} + \cdots + \hat\phi_p r_{t-p},$$
and the associated residual is
$$\hat a_t = r_t - \hat r_t.$$
The series $\{\hat a_t\}$ is called the residual series, from which we obtain
$$\hat\sigma_a^2 = \frac{\sum_{t=p+1}^T \hat a_t^2}{T-2p-1}.$$
If the conditional likelihood method is used the estimates of $\phi_i$ remain unchanged, but the estimate of $\sigma_a^2$ becomes $\tilde\sigma_a^2 = \hat\sigma_a^2 \times (T-2p-2)/(T-p)$.

What are the conditional least-square and conditional-likelihood methods? Why does the estimate $\hat \sigma_a^2$ have $T-2p-1$ in the denominator if the conditional least-square method is used and not $T-p$ like $\tilde \sigma_a^2$, since, after all, there are $T-p$ summands in the numerator?
